# Knockoutjs does not update value when select options changed

Tags: knockout.js

Problem is when select options got changed value is not being updated.

So when I change Honda to Toyota, options in second select got changed fine, but selectedModel observable not. I must have missed something.

JavaScript:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedMake = ko.observable()
    self.selectedModel = ko.observable()

    self.makes = ["Honda", "Toyota"];
    self.models = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.selectedMake() === "Honda") return ["CRV", "Accord"];
        if (self.selectedMake() === "Toyota") return ["Rav4", "Camry"];
        return [];
    });
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedMake, options: makes"></select>
<select data-bind="value: selectedModel, options: models"></select>
<p>Selected make: <b data-bind="text:selectedMake"></b></p>
<p>Selected model: <b data-bind="text:selectedModel"></b></p>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apuchkov/n4VyD/

Comment: It gets odd when you change make, then change back. At that point, it's looking at the previous value of models.

Comment: I know this a old post. The issue is fixed in the latest knockoutjs lib(3.2.0)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4VyD/93/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got an answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/935#issuecomment-17061341). Reposting it here if someone will find this question.

This is a case where the order of the bindings matter. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html#notes_for_multiple_bindings_on_a_single_element

```
<select data-bind="options: makes, value: selectedMake"></select>
<select data-bind="options: models, value: selectedModel"></select>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4VyD/4/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's not working as is, but if you set up a subscription to models, you can manually change the selected model.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedMake = ko.observable()
    self.selectedModel = ko.observable()

    self.makes = ["Honda", "Toyota"];
    self.models = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.selectedMake() === "Honda") return ["CRV", "Accord"];
        if (self.selectedMake() === "Toyota") return ["Rav4", "Camry"];
        return [];
    });

    self.models.subscribe(function(value) {
        self.selectedModel(value[0]);
    });
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4VyD/2/)

Comment: Good workaround, thanks. Can be even simplified to self.selectedModel(value); Still curious what's wrong with original example. If something is missing or it's Knockout bug.